OpenXPKI - handling an invalid issued certificate
I am working with a test installation of OpenXPKI v3 running in a FreeBSD-13.3 jail.  As part of my testing I issued a certificate with the incorrect SubjectAlternateName (SAN). I revoked this certificate as that is how we handle such situations with our existing CA software.  However, when I went to re-issue a corrected certificate I discovered that one cannot issue multiple certificates for a single primary key using OpenXPKI, even if the prior certificates are expired or revoked.
I asked about this on the OpenXPKI list and was told that this is a check that can be disabled. What I would like to discover is how the circumstance of replacing a incorrect certificate is handled other than by revocation and replacement.  The primary key in this instance is not compromised as the error occurred entirely during the signing process.  Changing primary keys is not really desired.
